# Why Won't My Simple Icons Appear?

Tags: css

I'm working on a "flat design" website, and I've decided to use Simple Icons. I wanted the background of the Simple Icon to get darker while the white overlay image stays the same. So, I created a list (it's a navbar). I also put an anchor inside of the list item. I tried setting the background image to the anchor as the icon, and the background color to the list item to whatever I wanted. I also tried adding a transition to the list item to change the background color, but that didn't work so I just got rid of it. Here is the CSS for that entire piece of the site:

```
div#nav{
float:right;
width:auto;
height:37px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:5px;
background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
border-left-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border-right-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border-right-width:1px;
border-right-style:solid;
border-left-width:1px;
border-left-style:solid;
border-top-width:1px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
margin-top:102px;
margin-left:2px;
}
#nav ul{
padding:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
}
#nav ul li{
width:32px;
height:32px;
margin-left:15px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
border:0;
}
#nav ul li a{
z-index:10;
}
#facebook{
width:32px;
height:32px;
background-image:url('images/facebook.png');
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a id="facebook" ></a></li>
<li><a id="twitter" ></a></li>
<li><a id="youtube" ></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I didn't include styling for the id "twitter" or "youtube" because I'm just trying to get it to work with one for now. Can anyone make the simple icons appear AND make the transition work? I'll provide the simple icons. The icon images are inside a folder called "images" inside of another folder called "_css" which contains the CSS file itself.

https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-32.png

Comment: `https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-32.png` is either blank or I need an eye exam.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link to your website?

Comment: @j08691 I would have to say the same.

Comment: @j08691 it might be possible that your eyes are going bad. View it in firefox, on my machine the background is all dark and the iamge is a facebook icon but it is fairly light

Comment: @Huangism - good call. At least I know it's not my eyes.

Comment: You can't see it because it has a transparent background with a white image. The picture is located in the top-left corner.

Comment: The website isn't up yet, that's why I'm still building it.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
display: block;
```

to your anchors

anchor tags are naturally display inline and since you have no content in the anchors so you will not see them despite giving them the dimensions

Comment: beat me by a mere 10 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

```
display: block;
```

add this to your `<a>` tags

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9CFGK/